# Hide a button based when on a particular page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to hide a button on a particular page. How can i accomplish this?

i have tried using the `ng-show` but that did not work

Html

```
<md-button id="btnReturn" class="md-raised md-primary"
           ng-click="onBackToMenuClicked()" ng-hide="onCrossWalkClicked()"> 
  {{'BTN_RETURN_lbl' | translate}}
</md-button>
```

JS

```
$scope.onCrossWalkClicked = function(){
    if ($location.path('url')){
        btnReturn.style.display === "none"
        return true;
    }
```

button should hidden on the current page

Comment: are you sure that `$location.path('url')` is true?

Answer (score 0):

While not a good pattern, you aren’t using $location.path() correctly.

> path([path]);
>
> This method is getter / setter.
>
> Return path of current URL when called without any parameter.
>
> Change path when called with parameter and return $location.

You are including a parameter in your if statement, so you are setting the path. You want to check if the url path is equal to a specific path, like this.

```
if($location.path() === “/url”){
     // do something 
}
```

The more common way would be to assign the $location.path() comparison to a scope variable to use in your ng-hide or ng-show.

```
//In your controller 
if ($location.path() === “/url”){
     $scope.hideButton = true;
} else {
     $scope.hideButton = false;
}

// in template 
<md-button ng-hide=“hideButton”>text<md-button>
```

(Answered from mobile. Formatting might not be great)